# iOS10 iphone5/5c JavaScriptCore crash

Tags: ios10, javascriptcore

I find out app crash frequently, and it is caused by some error in JavascriptCore framework.

[image: first crash report]

[image: second crash report]

As you see, these crashed all happened on iOS 10 and iPhone5/5c. So I doubt that the system has some bugs. Can anyone help me to get a solution?

Comment: It's hard to debug when crashes are formatted like this. Try using Crashlytics (free) to get more detail crash reports.

Answer (score 0):

After long time testing and exploring, I have fonud it is caused by low memory issues with UIWebView on iOS 10. I believe it is a system bug, and I replace UIWebView with WKWebView in my application. And now the crash never happened any more.